# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() is returning Null in Service Layer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

In service layer, I used ***getAuthentication()*** but return null. but in controller, it work well.

Please help me.

Update:

I had security.xml:

```xml
<beans>
    <security:http realm="Protected API"
                   use-expressions="true"
                   auto-config="false"
                   create-session="stateless"
                   entry-point-ref="JvCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
                                position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                                access="isAuthenticated()"/>

        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    <bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="vn.jupviec.api.cleanerapp.auth.JvCustomAuthenticationProviderImpl"/>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
                ref="customAuthenticationProvider">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="JvCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint"
          class="vn.jupviec.api.cleanerapp.auth.JvCustomAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

    <bean id="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter"
          class="vn.jupviec.api.cleanerapp.auth.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

bla

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. There Is way too little information to be able to formulate an answer.

Comment: I realized, In Service Layer, it had diff threadId with Controller. What happen?

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried to implement getCurrentUserLogin in SecurityUtils class. 
It used ***SecurityContextHolder.getContext()*** and it work well in Controller layer. 
But in ServiceLayer ***getAuthentication()*** return null. 
I dont know. I used springboot 1.5

Comment: Don't describe, show code, show configuration.